# Weird setup in the differentiability definition of vector-to-vector functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm studying the book *Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics* by Magnus and Neudecker (1988). Within there (Chapter 5, Section 4), the authors gave the following definition of differentiability of vector-to-vector function:

**Definition 5.2:** Let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function defined on a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $c$ be an interior point of $S$, and let $B(c;r)$ be an $n$-ball lying in $S$ (this is just an open $n$-dimensional ball with center $c$ and radius $r$). Let $u$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $||u|| < r$, so that $c+u \in B(c;r)$. If there exists a real $m \times n$ matrix $A$, depending on $c$ but not on $u$, such that

$$f(c+u) = f(c) + A(c) u +r_c (u)$$

for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $||u|| < r$ and

$$\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{r_c(u)}{||u||} = 0,$$

then the function $f$ is said to be differentiable at $c$.

---

I find this to be a totally reasonable definition. However, my question is, why is it necessary to introduce $B(c;r)$ in the definition? Couldn't we rewrite the definition as follows?

**Definition 5.2 (modified):** Let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a function defined on a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $c$ be an interior point of $\mathcal{S}$. Let $u$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $c+u \in S$. If there exists a real $m \times n$ matrix $A$, depending on $c$ but no on $u$, such that

$$f(c+u) = f(c) + A(c) u +r_c (u)$$

for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $c+u \in S$ and

$$\lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{r_c(u)}{||u||} = 0,$$

then the function $f$ is said to be differentiable at $c$.

Comment: Formally it is the same. But: 1) differentiability is a local property, and choosing a small ball emphasises that, 2) it is the standard way of thinking, 3) it is nicer to have the function $r_c$ defined on a ball than on something weird and 4) once you write $\lim_{u\to 0}$ later, you are actually starting to restrict to a small ball around $c$ anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modified definition is absolutely okay. It is in fact the "standard definition" used in most textbooks. See for example Definition 9.11 in

> Rudin, Walter. Principles of mathematical analysis. Vol. 3. New York: McGraw-hill, 1964.

It is also common use to avoid the use of *remainder function* $r_c$ and to require simply

$$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{f(c+u) - f(c) - A(c)u}{\lVert u  \rVert} = 0 \tag{1}$$
or
$$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\lVert f(c+u) - f(c) - A(c)u \rVert}{\lVert u  \rVert} = 0 \tag{2}$$
which is equivalent to $(1)$. But it is a matter of taste to use $r_c$ or to avoid it.

In all definitions the subtlety lies in the understanding of $\lim_{u \to 0}$. Forming the quotients is only possible if $c + u \in S$. Thus actually we have to consider the function
$$\phi : S'_c \to \mathbb R^m, \phi(u) =  f(c+u) - f(c) - A(c)u$$
which is defined on the set
$$S'_c = \{ u \in \mathbb R^n \mid c + u \in S \} .$$
Since $c$ is an interior point of $S$, we see that $0$ is an interior point of $S'_c$ which implies that $0$ is a limit point of $S'_c \setminus \{0\}$ so that
$$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\phi(u)}{\lVert u \rVert}$$
is well-defined.

Since $0$ is an interior point of $S'_c$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(0;r) \subset S'_c$. This explains the use of $r$ in the original definition. It assures that $x + u \in S$ for $\lVert u \rVert < r$. However, it also means that we consider the function
$$\psi : B(0;r) \to \mathbb R^m,  \phi(u) =  f(c+u) - f(c) - A(c)u$$
instead of $\phi$.

Let me finally remark that one normally uses linear maps $L : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb  R^m$ instead of $(m \times n)$-matrices $A$. This means that one requires the existence of a linear map $L = L(c)$ such that
$$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{f(c+u) - f(c) - L(c)(u)}{\lVert u  \rVert} = 0 .\tag{3}$$
Of course linear maps $L$ have unique matrix representations $A_L$ such that $L(u) = A_L \cdot u$, where $\cdot$ denotes matrix multiplication and $u$ is regarded as a column vector (which is an $(n \times 1)$-matrix).

In your textbook $\mathbb R^n$ is introduced as the set of ordered $n$-tuples $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ with $x_i \in \mathbb R$. Later we read

> An $(m × 1)$-matrix is a point in $\mathbb R^{m \times 1}$ (that
> is, in $\mathbb R^m$) and is called a (column) vector of order $m \times 1$.

You should be aware that the author **identifies** $\mathbb R^m$ with $\mathbb R^{m \times 1}$ which is the key to write $Au$ for a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ and a vector $u \in \mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably for proof or further aplications we need whole story of equation will happen in the ball. In your definition it is not entirely sure if nothing will come out of the ball